If the integral of a monotonic f converges, does it mean f approaches 0?
I have come across this question:
Say $f(x): [0,\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is monotonic non-increasing, and $\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x)dx$ converges.
Does it mean that $\lim_{x\to\infty}{f(x)}=0$? If so, can you help me prove it?
Thanks:)

Do you mean $\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)dx$ converges?

if $\int_0^{+\infty}f(x)dx<\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to +\infty} f(x)$ exists, then the limit is $0$

Assume otherwise and show that the riemann sum must diverge.


First of all, the limit in question must exist (either a finite number or $-\infty$), since $f(x)$ is monotonic and nonincreasing.
Let $A=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x) $. If $A>0$, then $f(x) \geqslant A>0$ for all $x\in[0, +\infty)$ and for any arbitrarily large $X$ we get $\int\limits_0^X f(x) dx \geqslant \int\limits_0^X A dx = AX$, which tends to (positive) infinity when $X\to\infty$.
If $A<0$ (including negative infinity), then for some $\varepsilon \in (A, 0)$ (e.g. we may take $\varepsilon=\dfrac12A$) exists $x_0$ such for any $x>x_0$ we have $f(x)\leqslant\varepsilon<0$, and $\int\limits_{x_0}^X f(x) dx \leqslant \int\limits_{x_0}^X \varepsilon dx = \varepsilon (X-x_0)$, which tends to (negative) infinity when $X\to\infty$, since both $x_0$ and $\varepsilon$ are fixed.
Since both option contradict the fact that the integral converges, we must have $A=0$.


https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards?cb=1

Not only is contetx missing this is also a duplicate. It has been answered many many times.
